# EF Core: SQLite delete is not cascading

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to add a database to my WPF application using SQLite and Entity Framework Core. Everything seems to work as it should, except the .Remove() call, which removes the element as expected, but is not cascading to other tables.

The Context class:

```
public class PersistenceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Network> Networks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("foreign keys=true;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(App.ApplicationPath, "persistence", "data.db"));
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()));

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

The remove method call:

```
public void RemoveEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        lock (persistenceContext)
        {
            switch (entity)
            {
                case Server server:
                    persistenceContext.Servers.Remove(server);
                    break;
                case Network network:
                    persistenceContext.Networks.Remove(network);
                    break;
            }
            persistenceContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The Migration class generated by `Add-Migration Initial`:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "JavaSettings",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                MaxRam = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                JavaPath = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                StartupParameters = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_JavaSettings", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ServerVersion",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Type = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Version = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                Build = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                JarLink = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ServerVersion", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "SimpleTime",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Hours = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Minutes = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_SimpleTime", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Networks",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UID = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                ProxyType = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                JavaSettingsId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                SyncServers = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Initialized = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                StartWithFork = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                ServerIconId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                VersionId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Networks", x => x.UID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Networks_JavaSettings_JavaSettingsId",
                    column: x => x.JavaSettingsId,
                    principalTable: "JavaSettings",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Networks_ServerVersion_VersionId",
                    column: x => x.VersionId,
                    principalTable: "ServerVersion",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "RestartTime",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                TimeId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_RestartTime", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_RestartTime_SimpleTime_TimeId",
                    column: x => x.TimeId,
                    principalTable: "SimpleTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "StartTime",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                TimeId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_StartTime", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_StartTime_SimpleTime_TimeId",
                    column: x => x.TimeId,
                    principalTable: "SimpleTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "StopTime",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                TimeId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_StopTime", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_StopTime_SimpleTime_TimeId",
                    column: x => x.TimeId,
                    principalTable: "SimpleTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Servers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UID = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                VersionId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                JavaSettingsId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                Initialized = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                StartWithFork = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                AutoSetSha1 = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                ServerIconId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                ResourcePackHashAge = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                Restart1Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                Restart2Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                Restart3Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                Restart4Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                AutoStop1Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                AutoStop2Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                AutoStart1Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                AutoStart2Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Servers", x => x.UID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_JavaSettings_JavaSettingsId",
                    column: x => x.JavaSettingsId,
                    principalTable: "JavaSettings",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_RestartTime_Restart1Id",
                    column: x => x.Restart1Id,
                    principalTable: "RestartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_RestartTime_Restart2Id",
                    column: x => x.Restart2Id,
                    principalTable: "RestartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_RestartTime_Restart3Id",
                    column: x => x.Restart3Id,
                    principalTable: "RestartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_RestartTime_Restart4Id",
                    column: x => x.Restart4Id,
                    principalTable: "RestartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_ServerVersion_VersionId",
                    column: x => x.VersionId,
                    principalTable: "ServerVersion",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_StartTime_AutoStart1Id",
                    column: x => x.AutoStart1Id,
                    principalTable: "StartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_StartTime_AutoStart2Id",
                    column: x => x.AutoStart2Id,
                    principalTable: "StartTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_StopTime_AutoStop1Id",
                    column: x => x.AutoStop1Id,
                    principalTable: "StopTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Servers_StopTime_AutoStop2Id",
                    column: x => x.AutoStop2Id,
                    principalTable: "StopTime",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Networks_JavaSettingsId",
            table: "Networks",
            column: "JavaSettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Networks_VersionId",
            table: "Networks",
            column: "VersionId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_RestartTime_TimeId",
            table: "RestartTime",
            column: "TimeId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_AutoStart1Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "AutoStart1Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_AutoStart2Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "AutoStart2Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_AutoStop1Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "AutoStop1Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_AutoStop2Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "AutoStop2Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_JavaSettingsId",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "JavaSettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_Restart1Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "Restart1Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_Restart2Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "Restart2Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_Restart3Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "Restart3Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_Restart4Id",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "Restart4Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Servers_VersionId",
            table: "Servers",
            column: "VersionId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_StartTime_TimeId",
            table: "StartTime",
            column: "TimeId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_StopTime_TimeId",
            table: "StopTime",
            column: "TimeId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Networks");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Servers");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "JavaSettings");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "RestartTime");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "ServerVersion");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "StartTime");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "StopTime");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "SimpleTime");
    }
}
```

I searched for this problem and found out that SQLite has not enabled cascading by default so i added `foreign keys=true;` to the connection string.
I also just in case added `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` to every connection like this:

```
persistenceContext.Database.GetDbConnection().StateChange += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        persistenceContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    }
};
```

How can i fix this issue and make delete cascading?

Comment: You probably want to set up a that for the database as a whole.

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you elaborate on that? The database as a whole is created with migration, what should i change?